# Start MT_ORDER_APP07 app in change mode for a specific PM order?

Tags: webdynpro

Using SAP standard Maintenance processing WDA

http://server:nnnn/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/mt_order_app07?sap-language=EN#

Opens this as expected

[image]

We want start in Change for a given order.

I looked at the Parameters for the app and IV_ORDERID is there
[image]

So I tried adding &IV_ORDERID=xxxxx to the URL
/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/mt_order_app07?sap-language=EN&IV_ORDER=000004000261#

but it didnt work.   Same result.

Can you open this WDA App in a given order ?
If so What would the correct URL Be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the activity type also `IV_ACTIVITYTYPE`, it is a mandatory parameter in this Webdynpro for processing. The possible values are:

**V** is `Change order`
**A** is `Display order`

The URL having these two parameters

```
http://server:port/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/mt_order_app?sap-language=EN&IV_ORDERID=80000007&IV_ACTIVITYTYPE=V
```

opened the PM order in change mode for me

[image]

I tried on `mt_order_app`, but they have the same parameters

Comment: It ignores the variable until you supply 2..  hahaha . You wouldnt want the user deciding if it was display or change they needed . Ie Order was locked. 
I was too fixated on why the orderid didnt work.  Nice work Suncatcher :)